# Собственный плагин jquery. Где хранить данные?

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

Имеется некоторый плагин, который производит некоторые манипуляции с объектом. При этом он сохраняет некоторые данные.

```
(function( $ ){
  var Myplugin = {
    defaults: {
      foo: 'bar'
    },
    options: null,
    init : function( options ) {
      Myplugin.options = $.extend(Myplugin.defaults, options);
      return this.each(function(c) {
        Myplugin.options.foo = 'здесь некие данные разные для каждого объекта';
      });
    }
};

  $.fn.myplugin = function( method ) {
    if ( Myplugin[method] ) {
      return Myplugin[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return  Myplugin.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Метод с именем ' +  method + ' не существует для jQuery.myplugin' );
    }
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Все хорошо, если объект один. Можно обратиться к myplugin и считать данные. Но когда объектов несколько, то данные одного объекта затирают данные другого объекта.

Как правильно хранить данные, чтобы они были доступны в любой момент?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так вы работаете с одним объектом, вот и проблема. Воспользуйтесь наследованием. Делается примерно так:

```
function Myplugin (a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.init();
}
Myplugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        // init
    },
    foo: function () {
        // некий метод
    }
}
```

Теперь вы можете создать сколько угодно экземпляров этого плагина используя `new`:

```
var myPlugin1 = new Myplugin(1, 2);
var myPlugin2 = new Myplugin(5, 6);
```

[**Вот хороший шаблон для создания таких плагинов**.](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/jquery-plugin-patterns/highly-configurable-mutable.html)

Comment: Пока что не совсем понимаю. Меня не устраивает new Myplugin(1, 2); Мне надо чтобы срабатывало как плагин jquery. Т.е. $('myElement').myplugin(options);

Comment: @AndrewGodin, значит немного не хватает базы, изучайте: https://learn.javascript.ru/prototypes

Comment: @AndrewGodin, посмотрите последнюю ссылку. Вот эту: https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/jquery-plugin-patterns/highly-configurable-mutable.html

Тут вы увидите как весь механизм с new оборачивается jQuery плагином.

Comment: Спасибо. Пошел изучать.